# Play! 2.0 DB isn't recognized

Tags: java, database, playframework-2.0, ebean

I'm new to Play! 2.0 with Java and I try to connect my new app to an existing database @work. I build my model class exactly on the existing columns within the DB, but it still tries to evolve my DB ("Database 'default' needs evolution!"). Do I need to change the config concerning the DB (e.g. because of the 'default' thing)?

Thanks for help.

Edit:

I solved my problem. I had to disable the evolutionplugin within the config. After that it accessed the data of the DB correctly.

Comment: Just for future reference, you do that by uncommenting the 'evolutionplugin=disabled' line in the application.conf file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for your knowledge:

**BE CAREFUL** when connecting existing DB with data to Play with evolutions, it can **destroy** your data!

Disabling evolutions is first step you should do.

Comment: Thanks. I was a bit shocked when I first saw the "Your DB needs evolution" screen as I was quite sure about having the model build up correctly.
But as well my first thought was "If I'd now click the apply-button, the DB certainly gets overridden." So I stopped the server immediatly and didn't click on the button.
My next two thoughts were if my config might be wrong or my model is. So I scanned the config and found that option and I gave it a try. Tada, the access worked.
The problem was (I think), that the initial samples all worked with new DBs and needed the evolution.

Comment: In general evolutions are good idea and you can include it anyway. Just don't use auto generated evolutions, but if you need to add new fields just write new evolution with ALTERS like described in [docs](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/Evolutions) and your existing data _should_ be safe. However always remember that **DB backup is your friend**